# Intellij Idea: Getting rid of the generated space after each opening square-brackets in html files

Tags: intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I usually use the reformat option of Intellij IDEA during coding, and I configured it as I wish, but it disappoints me sometimes. In the Theymeleaf HTML file, suppose there is the following bunch of code:

```
<style th:inline="css">
    .input-error {
        direction: [[#{lang.dir}]];
        color: red;
        text-align: [[#{lang.line.begin}]];
    }
</style>
```

When I reformat the file, with the keyboard shortcut, it becomes like this:

```
<style th:inline="css">
    .input-error {
        direction: [ [#{lang.dir}] ];
        color: red;
        text-align: [ [#{lang.line.begin}] ];
    }
</style>
```

In the Thymeleaf `[ [#{lang.dir}] ]` is ***NOT*** acceptable, and it's necessary to be `[[#{lang.dir}]]`. So, How can I tweak the code style options of Intellij IDEA and prevent it from adding these spaces after the square-brackets after reformatting?

PS I tried to change: Settings --> Editor --> Code Style --> HTML

Comment: Did you try to use a separate file for the CSS style?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni no it's embedded within an html. I Also don't know how to use the Thymeleaf inside a separate css file and for instance use [ [#{lang.dir}] ]

Comment: Suggestion 1: Does the IDEA reformatter split your inline text if you wrap it in a comment, like this: `direction: /*[[#{lang.dir}]]*/;`? This is valid [natural templating](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#advanced-features-css-natural-templates-etc.) for Thymeleaf.

Comment: Suggestion 2: Does the IDEA reformatter also split `[(` and `)]`? For example, if you use `direction: [(#{lang.dir})];`? This is the difference between escaped and unescaped Thymeleaf text. That may be something you prefer not to use, because of this.

Comment: @andrewjames: The first suggestion works. But the second suggestion does not because IDEA reformatter splits it. Thank you buddy, you saved me ;-)